# Dynamic route without redirect

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs app and would like the homepage to depend on the logged in status of the user.

Im looking for something like the following to happen:

1. When I goto mypage.com use 'resolve' to perform an HTTP GET with a server to check if logged in.
2. If the user is not logged in resolve the promise from 1) and show some generic splash screen. For example, templateUrl: splash.html
3. If the user is logged in then fetch additional data from the server. Once the data has been returned then resolve the promise from 1) and show a page specific for this user. For example, templateUrl: loggedin.html

In either case, the URL should not change. ie: I do no want to redirect to another route. The URL should always be mypage.com.

How can I have a dynamic page like this without using any redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app, its the best example app I've found so far for dealing with the user authorization rabbit hole.

For a quick start with getting your head around how user auth works in angular-app, have a look at these 3 files:

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/app.js

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/security.js

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/authorization.js